# Magento cache doesn't keep files

Tags: magento, caching

Each time after refresh the /var/cache folder delete everything and rebuild, so the cache doesn't work normal.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this.

Comment: after refresh the cache folder ? can you pls explain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

1) Check cache configuration.  For background see:

https://www.mgt-commerce.com/blog/the-right-magento-cache-strategy-for-best-performance/

2) Check permissions of /var/cache, make sure they are not too restrictive. They should be 770.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12158/what-permissions-should-i-give-var-and-media